# cast to IEnumerable results in performance hit

Tags: c#, .net, performance, iteration

While analyzing an performance hit in our Windows CE based software, I stumbled upon a very 
fascinating mystery:

Look at these two methods:

```
void Method1(List<int> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item == 2000)
            break;
    }
}

void Method2(List<int> list)
{
    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<int>)list)
    {
        if (item == 2000)
            break;
    }
}

void StartTest()
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        list.Add(i);

    StartMeasurement();
    Method1(list);
    StopMeasurement(); // 1 ms

    StartMeasurement();
    Method2(list);
    StopMeasurement(); // 721 ms
}

void StartMeasurement()
{
    _currentStartTime = Environment.TickCount;
}

void StopMeasurement()
{
    var time = Environment.TickCount - _currentStartTime;
    Debug.WriteLine(time);
}
```

`Method1` takes 1 ms to run. `Method2` needs nearly 700 ms !
Don't try to reproduce this performance hit: it won't appear in a normal program on PC.

Unfortunately we can reproduce it in our software on our smart devices very reliably. The program runs on Compact Framework 3.5, Windows Forms, Windows CE 6.0.
The measurement uses `Environment.TickCount`.
As it is quite clear that there must be a strange bug in our software which slows down the enumerator, I simply can't imagine what kind of error could let the `List` class slow down, only if the iteration is using the `IEnumerable` interface of List.

And one more hint: After opening and closing a modal dialog (Windows Forms), suddenly both methods take the same time: 1 ms.

Comment: While I would expect it to be slower, I wouldn't expect it to be 721x slower.  I highly suspect that there are problems with how you're measuring this operation if you're getting those kinda of results.

Comment: You're measuring this only once?

Comment: I ran this and got 1.51 ms and 1.29 ms respectively.

Comment: Here's my suggestion: post the exact code for `StartMeasurement` and `StopMeasurement`. In particular, using `Environment.TickCount` is very well, but are your calculations on it correct? Does `TickCount` even return suffiiciently granular results on Windows CE?

Comment: The List enumerator is a struct which is very GC friendly and the method calls are non virtual which can be inlined due to the way how foreach works. foreach can enumerate items in objects which do not implement IEnumerable. If you cast it to IEnumerable you force the compiler to use the interface with virtual methods which cannot be inlined. Besides this the enumerator is boxed which would if called often put additional pressure on the GC.

Comment: @Jeroen: The source code of StartMeasurement:

    void StartMeasurement()
    {
     _currentStartTime = Environment.TickCount;
    }
    
    void StopMeasurement()
    {
     var time = Environment.TickCount - _currentStartTime;
     Debug.WriteLine(time);
    }

Answer (score 3):

You need to run tests several times, because in a single run the **CPU** might get suspended, etc. It is for instance possible that while running `method2`, you are moving with your mouse resulting in the OS temporary letting the mouse driver run, etc. Or a network package arrives, or the timer says it is time to let another application run,... In other words there are a lot of reasons why all of a sudden your program stops running for a few milliseconds.

If I run the following program (note that using `DateTime`'s, etc.) is not recommended:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    list.Add(i);

DateTime t0 = DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    Method1(list);
}
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    Method2(list);
}
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(t1-t0);
Console.WriteLine(t2-t1);
```

I get:

```
00:00:00.6522770 (method1)
00:00:01.2461630 (method2)
```

Swapping the order of testing results in:

```
00:00:01.1278890 (method2)
00:00:00.5473190 (method1)
```

So it's only 100% slower. Furthermore the performance of the first method (`method1`) is probably a bit better since for `method1`, the JIT compiler will first need to translate the code to machine instructions. In other words, the first method calls you do *tend to be a bit slower than the ones later in the process.*.

The delay is probably caused because if you use a `List<T>`, the compiler can **specialize** the `foreach` loop: it **already knows the structure** of the `IEnumerator<T>` at compile time and can **inline** it if necessary.

If you use an `IEnumerable<T>`, the compiler must use **virtual** calls and lookup the exact methods using a *vtable*. This explains the time difference. Especially since you don't do much in your loop. In other words, the runtime must lookup which method to actually use, since the `IEnumerable<T>` could be anything: a `LinkedList<T>`, a `HashSet<T>`, a datastructure you made yourself,...

A general rule is: the higher the type of object in the class hierarchy the less the compiler knows about the real instance, the less it can optimize performance.

Comment: Why are you using `DateTime` while saying "don't use it" ? :(

Comment: @cosmo0: because I have currently no access to an (offline) C# compiler to profile it. Neither using `DateTime`s or `Stopwatch`es is a good idea.

Comment: `Stopwatch` either ? So what method do you recommend ?

Comment: @cosmo0: I think one better uses a *profiler*. Using `StopWatch` can have side-effects like program caching, etc. Although that also counts for a profiler. A profiler however will aim to minimize the disturbance...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe generating the template code the first time for the IEnumerable?

Comment: That isn't going to take 720 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your comments.

Our development team is analyzing this performance bug for nearly a week now

We run these tests several times in different order and different modules of the program 
with and without compiler optimization. @CommuSoft: You are right that JIT needs more time to run code 
for the first time. Unfortunately the result is always the same: 
Method2 is about 700 times slower than Method1.

Maybe it's worth to mention again, that the performance hit appears untill we open and close any modal dialog in the program. It's not important what modal dialog. The performance hit will be fixed right after the 
method Dispose() of the base class Form has been called. (The Dispose method hasn't been 
overriden by a derived class)

On my way of analyzing the bug I stepped deeply into the framework and found out now, 
that List can't be the reason for the performance hit. Look at this piece of code:

```
class Test
{
    void Test()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();

        StartMeasurement();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            myClass.DoSth();
        }
        StopMeasurement(); // ==> 46 ms


        var a = (IMyInterface)myClass;
        StartMeasurement();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            a.DoSth();
        }
        StopMeasurement(); // ==> 665 ms
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    void DoSth();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void DoSth()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            double a = 1.2345;
            a = a / 19.44;
        }
    }
}
```

To call a method via the interface needs much more time than calling it directly.
But of course after closing our dubious dialog we measured between 44 and 45 ms for both loops.